# Getting median out of frequency table (counting sort)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I can't understand the logic behind getMedian method. How exactly median is evaluated, what is the connection between count of elements and sum of elements? Appreciate if someone could explain it's logic.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int[] ar = r.ints(0, 100).limit(9).toArray();
            int k = ar.length;
            int[] count = getCounts(ar);
            double median = getMedian(count, k);
            System.out.println(median);
        }

        private static int[] getCounts(int[] ar) {
            int[] count = new int[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
                count[ar[i]]++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        private static double getMedian(int[] count, int d) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
                sum += count[i];
                if (2 * sum < d)
                    continue;
                else if (2 * sum == d)
                    return (2 * i + 1) / 2.0;
                else
                    return i * 1.0;
            }
            return -1.0;
        }
```

Comment: Do you understand what a median is?

Comment: Yes, element in the middle of the sorted set.

Comment: Not always.  It's a value such that half the data are >=, and half are <= to it.  For an even number of observations, you average the largest value from the smaller half with the smallest value from the largest half, so it isn't necessarily an actual element in the set.  Looks to me like the algorithm is finding the counts per value, and iterating through until it steps on or over the halfway point of the total count.  It's using some tricks, but that's essentially it.

Comment: The devil is in the details, the rest is obvious.

Comment: Actually I think the algorithm is wrong.  It will give incorrect answers if there are an even number of values and there's a gap with 0 count exactly halfway through the count.

Comment: @pjs.: Yes the algrorithm is  complicated. I will post a simple one..working on it.

Comment: I have checked it thoroughly (as I could), it seems to be stable correct.

Comment: I haven't run it (been a few years since I dusted off the Java compiler), but does it report the median as 2 for the array [1, 1, 3, 3]?  If not, it's wrong.

Comment: It reports 1.5.

Comment: Then it's incorrect.  It should be averaging the 1 and 3 in the middle, and reporting 2.

Comment: yes it should be 2. Here it is not being done.

Comment: Yes, surprisingly, it fails for this particular elements, but I have tested it with large data and it passed that tests.

Comment: It's not surprising.  Given the correct definition of median I constructed a scenario designed to cause an incorrect algorithm to fail.  A program isn't correct because it sometimes gets the correct answer, it has to get the correct answer in the corner cases as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a relation because it is a frequency table. You are thinking it differently but let me give you an example.

`1 1 1 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5` if this is the array then the frequency table would be :-

```
1 3 4 5
- - - -
3 2 3 4
```

So this is [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).
So now I am adding every element count and asking us the question, where does the median lie? or where is that indexm which if I consider I will cover the middle element?

Now here I am checking if sum > d/2 then it's done. We found the median.else if it is less then I still have to traverse other elements to get to the middle of the array. And if it is sum==d/2 then we have found it but we have to send the correct position. And we simply send the one in the lower middle (happens in case like `1,1,1,1`).

### Walk through

1 1 1 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 5

Now I check if I traverse all set of 1's where I am? I covered 3 elements. But it's not the half of the total numbers(6).

Now add number of 3's. 5. This is also not.

Now I add number of 4's, So 8 elements I covered. So I covered more than half of number of elements. So median lies here.

### More detailed explanation:

You are asked to find the median of an array of 10 integers.

`[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`

Then median is in element at position floor(9/2)=4, which is 5 Right?

`[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5]`

Where is the median element at position floor(9/2)=4, which is 3. Right?

So now think this,

```
 1  2 3 4 5
 2  2 2 2 1
```

Now you will try to find the floor(9/2) th element here starting from beginning. And that's why you need to find the sum of the frequencies and all.

Hope you get it?

### Correct algorithm

What you need to do is :-

```
N = number of elements.
F[] = frequency array
so if N is odd
  find the element at floor(N/2)-th place and median is that element.
else
  find the element at floor((N-1)/2) and floor(N/2) th position and return their average.

Finding the element is simple:
Find( F[], p) // find the element at position p
{
  p=p+1
  for i in [0..|F|]
    cumulative+=F[i]
    if cumulative == p
      return this element.
    else cumulative >p
      return this element  
}
```

Comment: But algorithm does not count numbers, it accumulates sum of numbers.

Comment: @joe.d.: It is storing the frequencies. And then getting sum of them. Check it out.check teh `count` array.

Comment: Exactly, but I am not getting the relationship between sum and index.

Comment: @joe.d What it's summing are the counts of the values.  The indices of the count array are the values.

Comment: That is clear. What is not clear, relationship between accumulated sum(`sum`) and and index(`d`).  `if (2 * sum < d) continue`

Comment: @joe.d That's the same as checking if the sum is less than half the total count.  Divide both sides by 2 to confirm.

Comment: @joe.d: Median is the middle element in the middle of the sorted array. I guess if you know this you will understand.

Comment: Sorry, still it is not clear , we are comparing sum to index. :(

Comment: @joe.d: Wait I will try to explain different way.

Comment: I think I got it, it is counting frequencies , not values.

Comment: @joe.d.: Check my explanation...if it helps let me know.

Comment: @coderredoc Your first detailed example has 9 numbers rather than 10.  If it were the numbers 1 through 10, the median would be 5.5.

Comment: @pjs.: Yes look to be honest, I just explained the frequency part. And yes I will correct it but yes the algorithm should be different..I will just change the errors now. And later will come back to it.

Comment: @pjs.: Check the algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: @pjs.: The elements of the frequency array traversed in the sorted order from lower to higher. Can you show me why they won't be adjacent? `1 2 3 4` or `1 1 2 2` everyhere for even number of sorted elements it would be adjacent!!!

Comment: @pjs.: Look for this one...we will try to find the 1st and 2nd element ( 0 based indexing) and return their average. Same in the other array? You get my point?

Comment: @pjs: N here is the sum of all the frequency array elements. Thats why I can attack the problem from N/2 or (N-1)/2 positioned element.

Comment: @pjs.: Please let me know of your opinion and if I am getting anything wrong. I am always open to modify the answer to make it better. Thanks.